# Why print_r and var_dump shows private member values?

Tags: php

When var_dump($object) or print_r($object) is run, all the values of private members are shown.

Sample code:

```
class Test
{
    private $var1 = 'not to be accessed outside class';
    private $var2 = 'me too';
    private $var3 = 'same here';

    public function somefunction()
    {
    // to do code
    }

}
$object = new Test;
print_r($object);
```

Result:

```
    Test Object ( [var1:Test:private] => not to be accessed outside class [var2:Test:private] => me too [var3:Test:private] => same here )
```

I tried PHP different versions of PHP (5.x, 7.1), but the same result.

Can this be a bug?

Comment: why would it  not ?

Comment: If private members are accessible by var_dump whats the point in making it private?

Comment: I think this is not a bug..... These two function is simply use for showing data of any variable.. Here You are calling that class in which these private variables are located, so obviously all variable assigned in $object variable.. and var_dump() & print_r() print them..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php how could it possibly be invisible to php itself? **The visibility of a property, a method or (as of PHP 7.1.0) a constant can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords public, protected or private. Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.**

Comment: `print_r` and `var_dump` are for debugging. How are you supposed to debug your program if you can't see all the data?

Comment: when i use print_r and var_dump on a PDO object I dont see any details of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug, it is just showing the structured information about the data you are providing. Showing private property doesn't mean that it is making them accessible from outside. It just giving the information.

This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Thank you for the information.I tried print_r() and var_dump() on a PDO object (eg: $pdo= new PDO, print_r($pdo). It doesn't show any details about the data. So how can I make an object of class like the PDO class?